Apache Ignite 2.16.0 SegmentationResolvers xml configuration
Apache Ignite 2.16.0 still does not recognize SegmentationResolvers xml configuration.
Does it still need to implement GridSegmentationProcessor ?
<beans:bean id="segmentationResolver" class="my.cluster.JdbcPingSegmentationResolver"/>
<beans:bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
<beans:property name="gridLogger">
    <beans:bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"/>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="workDirectory" value="#{systemProperties[igniteTmpDir]}"/>
<beans:property name="segmentationResolvers" ref="segmentationResolver" />
<beans:property name="segmentCheckFrequency" value="10000" />
<beans:property name="segmentationPolicy" value="NOOP" />
<beans:property name="waitForSegmentOnStart" value="true" />
<beans:property name="communicationSpi">....


What do you mean by "does not recognise"? Is there an error message? How have you implemented your resolver?

The SegmentationResolver implementation does not invoke with just xml configuration. We need to provide implementation for GridSegmentationProcessor, and invoke the Segmentation resolvers in it.
It looks like GridSegmentationProcessor implementation is required.
